# Need help to calculate phase velocity in subsequent echoes

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, ultrasound

I have the response signal of a piezoeletric transducer. I'm trying to acquire the phase velocity of the echoes I'm receiving. The resonancy frequency of the transducer is 5 MHz. I'm using an oscilloscope (Tektronix MSO 3054) to aquire the signal.

[image: Figure of the response of the piezoeletric transducer]

I can calculate the time propagation in the time domain, but I'm having a lot of difficulty to get the phase velocity. Is there a manual or somewhere else I can find to get it?

The reason I'm trying to get this is because of the following equation

$$
\Delta \varphi = 2\pi f \frac{2l}{V} = 2\pi f t
$$

Where $\Delta \varphi$ is the phase difference, $l$ is the thickness of the material, $V$ is the velocity of the wave, $t$ is the time of the wave propagation to get trough the material, and $f$ the frequency.

I'm willing to get the $\Delta \varphi$ to calculate $V$.

Comment: Are you sure your formula applies to an impulse excitation ? That looks more like sinusoidal excitation: for an impulse you would more likely use the group delay rather than the phase delay.

Comment: I saw this formula in an article. What happen is when an ultrasound wave pass trought a dispersive solid, each echo change it format slightly, wich turn it harder to measure the group delay. I can measure the group delay with cross correlation, but I'm not liking the results. Seems quit random, even after interpolation.